# What does "take the points raised" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

Sorry I lost the context of the phrase, but as far as I remember when I looked up the phrase on Google I felt it didn't matter. I felt it had one meaning. At any rate, could you tell me whatever meaning you know, or where I could look into it.

The phrase is:
"take the points raised". Is it an idiom?

**P.S:** I've just found the [post](http://www.englishforums.com/English/HaveYouEverGoneThere/bbjgrl/post.htm). Two guys discussing a grammar question. Now one of them wrote the following as a reply quoting from the other guy:

> So - and please help me understand this
>   - to take the points raised: ***"...not impossible, in my opinion, but 'Have you ever been there?' is more natural in the situations I can
>   think of"***
>
> Why? I tried to explain why it was both 'natural', and
>   correct grammar in terms of the sentence provided.

Comment: Does that mean, I take the points back. Points mean objections?! It looks different after I posted the question up.

Comment: No. It means to understand the points that were raised.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you "raise a point", you are bringing up an issue to be discussed.  After someone has raised a point, you can refer to it as "the point [that has been] raised."

One possible sense of *take* is *consider*, as in "take, for example, the lowly worm."  (You are not being asked to physically acquire a worm, but to think about some aspect of it.)

Thus, when you want others to examine the issue that someone brought up, you can ask them to "take the point raised".

Answer (score 6):

The quote is not the idiomatic "I take your point"; it's a more literal use of *points* as in "objectives" or "questions", and *take* as in "consider".

> **[point](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/point)** n.
>   15. An objective or purpose to be reached or achieved, or one that is worth reaching or achieving: *What is the point of discussing this issue further?*
>   16. The major idea or essential part of a concept or narrative: *You have missed the whole point of the novel.*
>   17. A significant, outstanding, or effective idea, argument, or suggestion: *Your point is well taken.*

> **[take](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take)** v.tr.
>   25.b. To consider; assume: Take the matter as settled.

This sense of *take* is often used with "Let's".

> Let's take the first question you asked.
>   Let's take your points one by one.

Thus, your "to take the points raised" can be rephrased as "to consider the issues that have been brought up".

Comment: It's quite strange that in this very specific context, I understand it as "to see", not "to consider". I don't know if you would agree with me.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: (pardon me, this is getting into serious use-mention confusion land) I don't see how "to see" could make any sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

The verb "to take" has various meanings, in addition to "to physically seize and remove something".

About conversation, it can mean:

- to accept or withstand something which is said in some way. "take a compliment"; "take an insult"; "take an order"
- to agree, concede or acquiesce: "I take your point." "Point taken." "I can take a hint."
- to understand or interpret a statement or situation. "So, I take it that you're quitting?"
- to consider something. "take into account"; "take into consideration"; "take the points raised"

These meanings overlap. To consider something, we understand and interpret it, and also we perhaps accept it to some degree.

In this case the writer probably means something like:

> In consideration and acceptance of the points raised, let me reiterate my revised idea so you can check whether I have the proper understanding.

Comment: +1, though I understand the quote to be saying, "I will address the ideas that you have mentioned as follows."

Comment: Note that "acceptance" here does not mean _agreement_ with these ideas (points). It means that they are recognized, and "on the table" for discussion. They are accepted for discussion or debate.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Please note that the expression ***to raise my point(s)*** is quite common in conversation. It means that the speaker has just brought *"his or her point(s)"* up into the discussion. The term ***"raised point(s)"*** refers to some ideas or arguments that were put forward by someone in the discussion.

Once someone has raised his or her points, anyone might invite everyone in the discussion to consider the points that were just made, in order to discuss the raised points in further details. One common expression among others is ***to take the points raised***, which means ***to consider that already mentioned points***. For further details on this typical usage, you can read Martha's and Hellion's answers.

My confusion was caused by unfamiliar punctuation (and quite likely, my non-native'ness) which convinced me to interpret that specific line in an unusual way (unusual both for anyone and myself, actually). In case you might be curious, you could read the details in the comments below. (If all you want is the answer to your original question, you don't really need doing so.)

Also note that the word ***take*** can mean several things. (Most seemingly simple words are like that. They seem to be easy, but actually, they can convey a wide range of different subtle senses. Quite often, they will convey multiple senses at the same time.) You can read Kaz's answer for more details on *take*.

The following is my original answer, based on the (mis)understanding that ***take the points*** in the question should be interpreted idiomatically. I leave it here because it is a useful piece of information by and in itself.

---

The phrase ***take someone's point*** is idiomatic.

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_someone%27s_point),

> **take someone's point**
>   *verb*
>   1. (*idiomatic*) To agree with what a person says; to understand a person's argument and be persuaded by it.
>   2. (*idiomatic*) To grasp the essential meaning of what a person is saying.
>
> *Synonyms*
>   - (*grasp the essential meaning*): get someone's point, see someone's point, take someone's meaning

Comment: Good information, but in the context given I can't agree that this is the actual use or the intended meaning; the surroundings clearly indicate that the person doesn't understand what's being said.

Comment: @Hellion I think it (*take the points*) can be either used literally (*let's consider these points*) or idiomatically (*to get someone's points*). I believe that it will depend on the intention of the speaker. If he wanted to say *let's take the points raised*, then it would be the literal usage. But if I understand the guy correctly, he asked for helps so he can understand the points.

Comment: I agree, he's asking for help to understand.  That's why I say that the meaning you've given cannot be valid; your meaning is saying "I (already) understand and agree", not "I need help to understand".

Comment: @Hellion Eh? *So - and please help me understand this - **to take the points raised** ...* Doesn't that mean the same thing as: *So - and please help me understand this - **to see the points raised** ...*? --If he ended the sentence before *to take*, and begin a new sentence with *Take the points raised, ...*, then it's no doubt that he meant *let's consider ...*, but he didn't.

Comment: @DamkerngT.,  I don't know what "to see the points raised" would mean there, so I don't think it's a valid rephrasing.

Comment: However, after you filter away the fluff, he really did start the sentence with "to take the points raised"; the interjected call for assistance and the connective "So" can be ignored for parsing purposes.

Comment: @Hellion Thanks. This really helps. Before your last comment, I still understand his sentence as: *So... and please help me understand this...* (this *and* was used to continue his thought from the previous sentence), and then he continued with *...* (in order to help me) *to take the points raised*. Perhaps, the use of that single dash made me thought that way. (I'm not used to the use of a single minus-sign for em-dash. If he used comma, I might perhaps be able to interpret his sentence just fine.)

Comment: @Hellion According to your interpretation, which I now think is right, that line should be interpreted as: *So, and please help me understand this, to take the points raised ...* This is quite fine in spoken language. Interpreting it this way makes it clear that both parties were invited *to take the points*, not him alone (which would sound more like he was trying to understand something, i.e. *let me take the points*, or *please help me take the points correctly*).